# What will URL Loading System actually do when I called 'URLProtocol: didLoadData:' in a custom URL protocol?

Tags: ios

I'm using a custom NSURLProtocol in order to do something before WebView get response，everything goes fine except this url `https://dou.bz/23o8PS`.

if I stop using NSURLProtocol, just let WebView load a request (init with URL), it works ok. But if the data was loaded from protocol, WebView seems does't treat it as a HTML file:
[image]

what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the `Content-Type` response header?

Comment: Post your code!  People can't debug code that they can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check header and found is :

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

maybe the other links is :

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return also the response to the webview. Put these three lines at the end of your `startLoading` protocol method:

```
[[self client] URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
[[self client] URLProtocol:self didLoadData: body];
[[self client] URLProtocolDidFinishLoading: self];
```

the `response` object is an instance of `NSHTTPURLResponse` in which you have to set a dictionary of headers (specifically, HTTP headers received with the response in any way).
the `body` is NSData that you already use in your method